# How to set ConsumeContainerWhitespace = true in vs 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

How to set ConsumeContainerWhitespace = true/false.
In report property i doesn't found it.
I got pageSetup, Code, References, Variables in report property.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the report body, click F4, select "Report" in the top dropdown (control list) - you get all other report properties:

[image]